# Parallel Boost Graph Library (PBGL) and ParMETIS

Tags: graph, parallel-processing

I want to read a graph from a text file (in parallel) and use the adjacency list data structure to do some computations on it. By computations, I mean doing parallel Jacobi relaxation method. I wanted to use ParMETIS to read the graph and then use PBGL (Parallel Boost Graph Library) to do the rest. ParMETIS output file is CRS. Is it the same as adjacency list? How can I access vertices and edges? And I don't have any good tutorial for PBGL. The following is incomplete:

http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/pbgl/documentation/

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *I want to read a graph from a text file (in parallel)*  Do you have a parallel file system to support parallel reading ?  If not, trying to read a file in parallel will probably slow your program down rather than speeding it up.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't have a parallel file system. So I may do it in serial. What do you suggest for reading a graph from a text file and distribute it between processors? I want to make an adjacency list for that graph.